# Contrast Color with Red

Tags: color, color-theory, color-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with the Color Combination for the Red](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2401/need-help-with-the-color-combination-for-the-red)

Can some one help me to find a color that contrast the color Red HEX: cd0001

I am looking for something i dark rang of Grey, Black or Brown..

Its for a Food Photo website.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2401/need-help-with-the-color-combination-for-the-red ?? both same ??